# Turning a Multi-Dimensional Array Into A Linear One Dimensional Array

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am a bit new to python and I have a large list of data whose shape is as such:

```
print(mydata.shape)
>>> (487, 24, 12 , 13)
```

One index of this array itself looks like this:

```
[4.22617843e-11 5.30694273e-11 3.73693923e-11 2.09353628e-11
    2.42581129e-11 3.87492538e-11 2.34626762e-11 1.87155829e-11
    2.99512706e-11 3.32095254e-11 4.91165476e-11 9.57019117e-11
    7.86496424e-11]]]]
```

I am trying to take all the elements from this multi-dimensional array and put it into a one-dimensional one so I can graph it.
I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
mydata.ravel()
```

Will make a new array, flattened to shape:

```
(487*24*12*13,)
```

or...

```
(1823328,)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using flatten()

```
mydata.flatten(order='C')
```

And order types depend on the following:
order: The order in which items from the NumPy array will be read.

- ‘C’: Read items from array row wise i.e. using C-like index order.
- ‘F’: Read items from array column wise i.e. using Fortran-like index
  order.
- ‘A’: Read items from an array based on the memory order of items